# pbcopy for Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

In MacOSX there's a command which can pipe the output of a command to the clipboard so that it can be pasted somewhere else in the GUI.

How can this be done from cmd.exe or with a PowerShell cmdlet?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Use something like:

`someCommand | clip`

That will pipe the result to the windows clipboard

Comment: Good suggestion.  This is a standard Windows utility.  On most systems, it's at `C:\Windows\system32\clip.exe`.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton right, but since that is part of the PATH variable, that does not need to be made explicit

Comment: My point and part of the reason I gave you an upvote was that I liked that you'd suggested a standard Windows utility, not something the OP was supposed to d/l from somewhere.  Most people know about PATH.

Comment: For posterity, if you want the content of a file it's 'type somefile.txt | clip'

Comment: Annoyingly windows echo adds a \r\n and has no echo -n ... so "echo test | clip" will have test\r\n in copy buffer ... echo|set/p="test"|clip ... addresses this *gross*

Comment: Does clip.exe get text from clipboard ?

Answer (score 12):

I'm using the Git Bash command shell for Windows, and as someone noted above, using `clip` is very annoying, because it also copies the carriage return at the end of the output of any command.  So I wrote this function to address it:

```
function cpy {
while read data; do     # reads data piped in to cpy
    echo "$data" | cat > /dev/clipboard     # echos the data and writes that to /dev/clipboard
done
tr -d '\n' < /dev/clipboard > /dev/clipboard     # removes new lines from the clipboard
}
```

So for example:

```
$ pwd | cpy  # copies directory path

$ git branch | cpy # copies current branch of git repo to clipboard
```

Comment: Good one. If you have GNU win32 utils installed you could trim out the line break with `tr` and still use `clip`, i.e: `pwd | tr -d \r\n | clip`

Answer (score 7):

In PowerShell, just pipe the text into [`Set-Clipboard`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard). For fast typing, you can use the alias `scb`. This doesn't add an extra line break like the `clip` utility does.

For example, this command puts the contents of `myfile.txt` on the clipboard:

```
gc .\myfile.txt | scb
```

Note that for objects that represent file system objects, `Set-Clipboard` will copy the object in the same sense that Explorer does when you Ctrl+C a file. If that's not what you wanted, pipe the object through `Out-String` first.

Comment: This is the most useful Powershell-specific answer IMO, and is cross-platform; i.e. works with pwsh on Mac, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Just for reference I had to copy my public key directly after Bitbucket was giving me a bad key warning. I was able to use @soandos answer like so:

`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | clip` to copy my key directly from the command line on a PC. (since command line sucks compared to terminal)

Answer (score 2):

Geoffrey Huntley originally wrote the pasteboard project for Windows which includes the `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` commands. The project is now maintained by Mingxiang Xue at https://github.com/uzxmx/pasteboard on GitHub.

You can download the binaries from the latest [release](https://github.com/uzxmx/pasteboard/releases/) or install the binaries with [scoop](https://scoop.sh):

```
scoop bucket add extras
scoop install pasteboard
```

Then the `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` commands will be available as you are used on macOS.

Comment: Another windows implementation https://github.com/yoggy/pbcopy

Answer (score 1):

This function replaces the standard Windows clip in Git Bash where a trailing newline is copied.

```
function clip {
    printf "$(</dev/stdin)" | cat > /dev/clipboard
}
```

This is based on [Matthew's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1171448/53227) which only preserves the last line and introduces a trailing newline. Using `printf` avoids the newline that `echo` adds.

Answer (score 1):

For use in **WSL/bash**. Add to `~/.bashrc`:

```
function pbcopy() {
    printf $(</dev/stdin) | clip.exe
}
export -f pbcopy
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `printf %s "$(...` to prevent % expansion in the input? I'm not sure why the printf is needed

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 and 11 add a couple of Aliases to your `$profile` on powershell to have a similar `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` commands OSX has.

Usually, should be on the following path:

- powershell 7:
  `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`.
- powershell 5: `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

So add to the end of the $profile the following:

```
New-Alias pbpaste Get-Clipboard
New-Alias pbcopy Clip
```

Then you can use pbcopy and pbpaste as you do on OSX:

```
echo "Hello World" | pbcopy
pbpaste
> Hello World!
pbpaste > a.txt
cat a.txt
> Hello World!
```

> Note: On `PowerShell` `cat` is an alias of `Get-Content`. So, feel free to use either `cat` or `Get-Content`

If you prefer to use the commands as they are without aliases you can always run that as:

```
echo "Hello World" | clip
Get-Clipboard
> Hello World!
Get-Clipboard > a.txt
Get-Content a.txt
> Hello World!
```